# Get value of text inputs generated by Javascript and store it using .Net C#

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, .net

This is my first post. I've been in trouble with this for a few days now. I have this HTML code:

```
<fieldset>
    <legend>Certifictions</legend>

    <div runat="server" id="divCert">
        <input runat="server" type="button" id="btnAddCert" class="Botones" value="Agregar Certificación" onclick="AddCertification()" />
        <input runat="server" type="button" id="btnRemoveCert"  class="Botones" value="Quitar Certificación" onclick="RemoveCert()"  />
        <br/>
    </div>
</fieldset>
```

As you can see, I add and remove text fields to `divCert` via javascript. This is the code:

```
var count1=0; 
function AddCertification() {
    document.getElementById("divCert").innerHTML += 
        "<input type='Text' runat='server' name='txCert_" + 
        (count + 1) + "' class='textBox' id='txCert" + (count1 + 1) + 
        "' placeholder='Insert Text'/>";

    count1 = count1 + 1;       
}

function RemoveCert() {
    var parent;
    var eleRemove
    if (count1 > 0) {
        parent = document.getElementById("divCert");
        eleRemove = document.getElementById("txCert" + (count1).toString());
        parent.removeChild(eleRemove);

        count1 = count1 - 1;
    }else {
        window.alert("There's nothing to remove");
    }
}
```

Now, what I want to do is get the value of the textbox generated in codebehind at the aspx.cs file, store it, and write it into a file. Something like this:

```
List<Object> list = new List<object>();
    foreach(TextBox found in divCer.Controls){
    list.Add(found.Value);
}
```

I know that code won't work, but something like it is what I want to do with the values from each textbox generated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you have a reason to have a server-side instance of these controls, you could get their values by

```
Request.Form["txCert" + i];
```

where `count` can be "communicated" to server side and `i` can iterate over `count`

Comment: thankx for your help. That was helpful. and solved my problem.